# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab equivalent in Safari?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, safari-extension

I'm trying to port of Chrome extension to Safari, not sure if it's actually possible. Just wondering if anyone has written a screen capture/crop style plugin in Safari and specially the question stated in the title.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`visibleContentsAsDataURL()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/SafariBrowserTab/SafariBrowserTab.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009793-CH1-DontLinkElementID_6)